# How to get my old terminal tab in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My terminal tab was like this:
[image]

But I don´t know what I did and now it looks like this:

[image]

Can someone help me to get it as in first image please, I will be so thankful

Comment: Did you changed the VS Code theme? Try to use previous one.

Comment: I didn´t. I just remember some menu appear and I clicked and then my terminal tab changed

Answer (score 0):

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/10546), tabs were included in the [April 2021 (1.56) update](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_56#_terminal) – the difference exhibited in your two screenshots stems from the new version of the integrated terminal.